# IF ERRORLEVEL 0 checking doesnt seem to work correctly

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a minimal batch script on my windows machine desktop which uses the

**FC**.exe tool to compare two text files also on my desktop.

My files to compare

**file1.txt** *contains one character* **a**

**file2.txt** *contains one character* **b**

My batch file

```
SET "result=success"

fc.exe "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file1.txt" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\file2.txt"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 SET "result=failed"

echo %result%

pause
```

I expect the var **result** to be **failed** *(as file1 is different to file2)*,

however the output shows it is **success**

I have tried changing the only character **b** to **a** in **file2.txt** and

running the batch file again, but the output shows the **result** var is still

**success**

Furthermore, I can append the following

```
...
echo %ERRORLEVEL% 
...
```

directly under the **fc.exe** cmd, and it prints 1 for the first test and 0 for

the second, this result should cause the **IF** loop to trigger but it does not.

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IF ERRORLEVEL X` checks if [errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) is equal or greater than `X` so `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0` checks if the errorlevel is less than 0. Use conditional execution or `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0`

Comment: If what you are saying is correct, then why do we also **GTR : Greater than >** and **GEQ : Greater than or equal >=**? Doesnt seem to be a well written language if **IF** implicitly calls one of the mentioned above...

Comment: @DavidBattenburg not sure what you asking. `IF ERRORLEVEL X` has different parser than `IF X GTR Y`  \  `IF X GEQ Y`  and are not exactly the same operation.

Comment: @DavidBattenburg, `errorlevel` is intended to indicate levels. You have to read `if errorlevel n` as `if the errorlevel is at least n`